# how to upload multiple images to mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am making an ecommerce site, i want to upload multiple images that can be used to show the products. my problem is that it only uploads one image where it is stored to the file i directed 'product_images' to and its details are stored in the db. only one. i want to be able to upload atleast 4. how can i do so?

Code:
FORM:

```
                  <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <div class="col-lg-6">    
                          <p>PRODUCT DETAILS:</p> <br />

                      <tr>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="position">Enter Product Name:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_name" id="prod_name" placeholder="Enter Product Name:" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="position">Enter Product Brand:</label>
                <td><select type="position" class="form-control" id="prod_brand" name="prod_brand">
                        <OPTION value="Select Model..."></OPTION>
                        <?php brand(); ?>
                    </select></td>

            </div>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="position">Enter Product Model:</label>
                <td><select type="position" class="form-control" id="prod_model" name="prod_model">
                        <OPTION value="Select Model..."></OPTION>
                        <?php query(); ?>
                    </select></td>
                    <?php close(); ?>
            </div>

    </tr>
             <tr>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="position">Enter Product Price:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_price" id="prod_price" placeholder="Enter Product Price:" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="position">Enter Product Description:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <textarea style="width: 500px; height: 251px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_desc" id="prod_desc" placeholder="Enter Product Description:" cols="20" rows="5" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

    </tr>

     <tr>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="position">Enter Product Quantity:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod_qty" id="prod_qty" placeholder="Enter Product Quantity:" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><tr>
                    <td><label for="position">Select Images:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="product_image[]" id="product_image" multiple=""></td>                        
            </div>
                  <!--<div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" id="file-1" class="file" multiple name="product_image[]">
                    </div>-->
            </tr>
    </tr>
                        <tr>
        <br /><td><input class="btn btn-info" type='submit' name='submit' value='Add Product' /></td>
    </tr>
                  </form>
```

INSERTING THE PRODUCT:

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

```
    $prod_name = strtoupper($_POST['prod_name']);
    $prod_brand = $_POST['prod_brand'];
    $prod_cat = $_POST['prod_model'];
    $prod_price = $_POST['prod_price'];
    $prod_desc = $_POST['prod_desc'];
    $prod_qty = $_POST['prod_qty'];
    $d = date("Y-m-d");

    $id_query = $connection->query("INSERT into products(product_cat, product_brand, product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_qty, date) 
VALUES ('$prod_cat','$prod_brand','$prod_name','$prod_price','$prod_desc','$prod_qty','$d')");

    $query = mysql_insert_id();     


    $rand = rand(5,9878967699);
foreach($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

    $name = $_FILES['product_image']['name'][$key];
    $tmpname = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $type = $_FILES['product_image']['type'][$key];
    $size = $_FILES['product_image']['size'][$key];


    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15); //will pick the random 15 first characters
    mkdir("product_images/$rand_dir_name/");

    $dir = "product_images/$rand_dir_name/";

    $move = move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $dir.$name);

    if($move) {
        //$query = mysql_query("insert into products (product_cat, product_brand, product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_qty, product_image, date) 
//VALUES('$prod_cat','$prod_brand','$prod_name','$prod_price','$prod_desc','$prod_qty','$rand_dir_name/$name',now())");
    $query = $connection->query("update products set product_image='$rand_dir_name/$name' where product_title='$prod_name'");

if($query) {
        echo "<script>alert('Adding a product is successful!!!.')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Adding a product is unsuccessful!!!.')</script>"; 
    }
    } else {
        echo 'Picture upload failed';
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have enough fields for this?

Comment: enough fields on the db or?

Comment: In the db yes, I see now you have only single `product_image` field.

Comment: i dont, so u suggesting i add like other 'product_image' fields in the db?

Comment: if i do so how will i add the details of the other images then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make another table to store the image links in and 'connect' it to the table products by its product id.

So:

```
table 'Products'
ID, ProductName, optional other columns for product details

table 'Images'
ID, ProductID, ImageSrc
```

Then select all products. And inside the while loop you select per product all corresponding images by ProductID.

This way you can store unlimited images per product.

If you only want 4 images, then just make 4 columns for the image links

**Update 1: answer on comment**

At first, start using PDO or otherwise mysqli instead of mysql.

Select your images like this

```
$products = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products");
if (mysqli_num_rows($products) > 0) {
    while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) {
        echo "<p>Images for ".$product['ProductName'].":<br>";
        $images = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE ProductID = ".$product['ID']."");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($images) > 0) {
            while ($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($images)) {
                echo "- ".$image['ImageSrc']."<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "No images";
        }
        echo "</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am facing another problem, i am storing the images details in another table, using the product name as identifier. now when i request the image linked to the product name, it only shows one. my problem is i cannot select multiple rows in a column `ImageSrc` with the same unique identifier `Product_name`

Comment: Use the ID as identifier as those is always unique. Are you using a while loop to select all images?